# Querying a field with special characters in solr

Tags: solr, special-characters

we index business names and search against them.  I need to now search or pull list of business name that has & in its name. Also similar such symbols.

Query Used : http:localhost:9080/solr/core1/select?q=busname:*\-*&wt=xml

Schema.xml : "field name="busname" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false""

I thought just giving escape character would get me the intended results.

Comment: whats the defination of the text field type ?

Comment: <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">

Comment: whiteSpaceTokenizer is used while indexing these fields.

Comment: [Update]solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactor - This was one of the filter, which removes these special characters while indexing stopping anyone to search with special chars.  I was able to identify the same using Analyser in solr admin page which was helpful in understanding how the data is getting indexed..